# Get values threshold from plt with hanning interpolation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an array with shape 100, 64 and I am plotting its values using `matplotlib`. The idea is to create some kind of heatmap and for that, I am using hanning interpolation.

```
PPCF = array([[9.85130815e-01, 9.83444108e-01, 9.85278319e-01, ...,
        3.47374574e-04, 5.34567861e-04, 8.12382449e-04],
       [9.82263360e-01, 9.84180075e-01, 9.82388688e-01, ...,
        4.32164553e-04, 6.81896555e-04, 1.08259822e-03],
       [9.82703961e-01, 9.81077421e-01, 9.83125462e-01, ...,
        5.67433109e-04, 8.87040759e-04, 1.42732094e-03],
       ...,
       [8.96150448e-01, 8.95389442e-01, 8.91256341e-01, ...,
        6.52226663e-01, 6.46063975e-01, 6.37740703e-01],
       [8.89012207e-01, 8.84747152e-01, 8.82939126e-01, ...,
        6.55943897e-01, 6.50286855e-01, 6.44593070e-01],
       [8.77769444e-01, 8.72979307e-01, 8.70720783e-01, ...,
        6.58986102e-01, 6.53866758e-01, 6.48602747e-01]])
```

and the plot function

```
ax.imshow(np.flipud(PPCF), extent=((-53.0, 53.0, -34.0, 34.0)),interpolation='hanning',vmin=0.0,vmax=1.0,cmap='bwr,alpha=0.5)
```

Which gives this appearance:

[image]

However, I would like to know the indices of the array where it is red. Is it possible to know the threshold for the different colors?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```py
im = ax.imshow(...)
cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
```

will show you how the values translate to color and you can use that to filter the plotted data.